# Instructor is convering a large portion of course in small period of time

Tags: graduate-school, coursework, course-design

We are taking a course in Mathematical Physics and due to pandemics, the semester period is reduced by at least a month than usual. The last few classes were rushed, the instructor barely give time to the big topics like Green function or Strum Liouville theory that should be given much time.

It is asked to give feedback to the course. We can complain, of course,  about this. But I think it's better to give an idea that can settle this problem. So I'm asking what can be done in such situation?

Answer (score 2):

I see that you are enrolled in an Indian institute. I work as a faculty in one of those institutes and so let me tell you there is an immense pressure from the university administration on faculties to "complete" the syllabus. Further, if a faculty does not complete the syllabus, few students may even complain against the faculty. Certainly, this is a difficult situation to deal with.

As I understand it is better to prepare on one's own. In this digital age you have plethora of excellent lectures available for free on Youtube, free pdf books on the web. So just use them for your learning and in case you encounter difficulties you can then try to reach to the respective faculty of the subject matter in your institute. If the faculty then denies to help you, then I guess you have all the right to complain against the faculty. Alternatively, you have stackexchange to post your doubts and clarify them. *Extend your arms, the right help will reach you.*